# My flutter code is erroring even though the code is right

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, web

I have written my code properly and installed all packages yet it errors out for a variable.

please help me

I am using the speech to text module and have imported and installed it but it is erroring

and i am new to flutter so please help me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Voice',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: SpeechScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpeechScreenState createState() => _SpeechScreenState();
}

class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
  stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _text = 'Press the button to start speaking';
  double _confidence = 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

thank you

Comment: Add the error that you get in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
stt.SpeechToText _speech;
```

You have to initialize this property or make it nullable as below

```
stt.SpeechToText? _speech;
```